# Parse angularjs or AND or query

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

I have to get checkpoints from my data collation which are track by objectId and match to one of this pointers. I have tried.

```
var checkpoint = Parse.Object.extend("Checkpoint");
        var q1 = new Parse.Query(checkpoint);
        q1.equalTo("mission", {
            __type: "Pointer",
            className: "Mission",
            objectId: mid
        });
        q1.equalTo("checkpointType", {
            __type: "Pointer",
            className: "CheckpointType",
            objectId: "HJBdFD1p5f"
        })

        var q2 = new Parse.Query(checkpoint);
        q2.equalTo("mission", {
            __type: "Pointer",
            className: "Mission",
            objectId: mid
        });
        q2.equalTo("checkpointType", {
            __type: "Pointer",
            className: "CheckpointTYpe",
            objectId: "m17T0wLzwl"
        })

        var q3 = new Parse.Query(checkpoint);
        q3.equalTo("mission", {
            __type: "Pointer",
            className: "Mission",
            objectId: mid
        });
        q3.equalTo("checkpointType", {
            __type: "Pointer",
            className: "CheckpointTYpe",
            objectId: "mXPtoIRsI2"
        })

        var compquery = Parse.Query.or(q1,q2,q3);
        return compquery.find({
            success: function (results) {
                console.log(results);

            },
            error: function (results, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

I have this code with me, it returns an empty array. Are there any ways to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of this code is a syntax error, in

```
className: "CheckpointTYpe",
```

should be `CheckpointType` in all queries, but in my code its only in first query

```
 var q2 = new Parse.Query(checkpoint);
    q2.equalTo("mission", {
        __type: "Pointer",
        className: "Mission",
        objectId: mid
    });
    q2.equalTo("checkpointType", {
        __type: "Pointer",
        className: "CheckpointType",
        objectId: "m17T0wLzwl"
    })

    var q3 = new Parse.Query(checkpoint);
    q3.equalTo("mission", {
        __type: "Pointer",
        className: "Mission",
        objectId: mid
    });
    q3.equalTo("checkpointType", {
        __type: "Pointer",
        className: "CheckpointType",
        objectId: "mXPtoIRsI2"
    })

    var compquery = Parse.Query.or(q1,q2,q3);
    return compquery.find({
        success: function (results) {
            console.log(results);

        },
        error: function (results, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```